# Get all files in a directory and all the files under all subdirectories

Tags: c#, file, directory

I'm having a little problem getting all the files under all folders and sub directories.. And keep the path..

Here is my code at this moment..

This should go through everything right? All sub directories and everything?

```
private List<String> DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        List<String> files = new List<String>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
            {
                files.Add(f);
            }
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                files.AddRange(DirSearch(d));
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }

        return files;
    }
```

But all I'm getting is 1 random file in 1 folder many sub directories from the root folder.
And this is how i call it:

```
string folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
addFilesFromFolder(DirSearch(folderName));
```

And this is the method that's adding them to an XML file...

```
private void addFilesFromFolder(List<string> files)
    {
        String appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString();
        String gpsPath = appDataFolder + "\\GameProfileSaver";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(gpsPath + "\\games.xml");
        XmlNode fileToAdd = doc.CreateElement("file");
        String gName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        XmlNode gameName = doc.SelectSingleNode("//games/game[gameName='" + gName + "']/Files");

        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            fileToAdd.InnerText = f;
            gameName.AppendChild(fileToAdd);
        }

        doc.Save(gpsPath + "\\games.xml");
    }
```

Comment: You can also look at [this version of GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx). It supports recursivity with the SearchOption parameter.

Comment: You could probably just do `foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))` and not have the recursive function.

Comment: Read up on [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving `XmlNode fileToAdd = doc.CreateElement("file");` inside the `for`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(gpsPath + "\\games.xml");
String gName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
XmlNode gameName = doc.SelectSingleNode("//games/game[gameName='" + gName + "']/Files");

foreach (string f in files)
{
    XmlNode fileToAdd = doc.CreateElement("file");                
    fileToAdd.InnerText = f;
    gameName.AppendChild(fileToAdd);
}
```

I suspect because you are reusing the `XmlNode`, you are only getting the last file in the list.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem... Just as simple as that.. I didn't think about moving that inside my foreach...